# How can I push to one array from a pop in another?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program to emulate a kid's football, baseball, stickball; any team game. 10 kids in an array. Each kid has a random power number. You know you always picked the best kids first, then so on and so on.  So my script generates a random number for the kid's power. Then sorts through the array to determine the two highest kid's powers and places them at the end of the array and pops them out into two new arrays called teamOne and teamTwo. Then they toss a coin to see who picks first, pretty much by an if-else loop with a while nested inside the if.

My sort works, as does the pop of the two team captains into the two new team arrays. My coin toss works, but then I am at loss. So I am asking for some direction or instructional material suggestions for this problem?

Here is my code, and thank you.

```
// generate a random number
let getRandNum = function (start, range) {
  let getRand = (Math.random() * range) + start;
  while (getRand > range) {
    getRand = (Math.random() * range) + start;
  };
  return getRand;
};

// array of 10 kids
var Kids = [{
    name: "Bobby",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Frankie",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Juan",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Sid",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Ellie",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Harry",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Chester",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Lucio",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Kim",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  }
];

// sort based on random number with thanks to:
//  https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

function compareValues(key, order = 'asc') {
  return function innerSort(a, b) {
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // property doesn't exist on either object
      return 0;
    }

    const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
      a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
    const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
      b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

    let comparison = 0;
    if (varA > varB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (varA < varB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return (
      (order === 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
    );
  };
}

console.log(Kids.sort(compareValues('random', )));

const teamOne = Kids.pop();
const teamTwo = Kids.pop();

console.log(teamOne);
console.log(teamTwo);
console.log(Kids);

let coinToss = "Heads"

if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1) == 2) {
  coinToss = "Tails";
};

console.log(coinToss);

if (coinToss = "Heads") {
  let x = 4;
  while (x > 0) {
    teamOne.push([Kids.pop()]);
    teamTwo.push([Kids.pop()]);
    x -= x;
  };
} else {
  let x = 4;
  while (x > 0) {
    teamTwo.push([Kids.pop()]);
    teamOne.push([Kids.pop()]);
    x -= x;
  };
  console.log("_____________");
  console.log(coinSide);
  console.log("_____________");
  console.log(teamOne.name);
  console.log("_____________");
  console.log(teamTwo.name);
};
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing with the code?

Comment: Everything below the if statement is not working. I am trying to return two teams of 5 players each.

Comment: Could you please specify which if statement? Because you have multiple of them.

Comment: I am trying to pop the remaining 8 kids out of the Kids array and split them into the TeamOne and  teamTwo arrays

Comment: Are you just sending the kids to the teams randomly or is there some sort of way to differentiate the teams?

Comment: The kids array is sorted lowest to highest random value. So the kids with the higher score are at the end. So the highest two are popped out to create the two new arrays. Like captains of their teams. Then they toss a coin. The if else depends on who wins the toss. Then its just highest next kid From the kids array gets selected. Then just back and forth between the teams. Like you did as a kid with your friends.

Comment: if (coinToss = "Heads")  this should be if (coinToss === "Heads") {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not treating teamOne and teamTwo as arrays, so you can not use "push".  On top of that, the Kids array objects have two values - "name" and "random" - so, using "push" would add a new kid as an object.

So, firstly, you need to define teamOne and teamTwo as arrays and not strings.  And, secondly, you need to extract the "name" property from the Kids objects (assuming that you were only using "random" for sorting purposes and no longer require it's value).  And, finally, you have not assigned a name to each team which, if you used an array for them, you could now do.

Try something like:

```
// generate a random number
let getRandNum = function (start, range) {
  let getRand = (Math.random() * range) + start;
  while (getRand > range) {
    getRand = (Math.random() * range) + start;
  };
  return getRand;
};

// array of 10 kids
var Kids = [{
    name: "Bobby",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Frankie",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Juan",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Sid",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Ellie",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Harry",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Chester",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Lucio",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  },
  {
    name: "Kim",
    random: getRandNum(1, 10)
  }
];

// sort based on random number with thanks to:
//  https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

function compareValues(key, order = 'asc') {
  return function innerSort(a, b) {
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // property doesn't exist on either object
      return 0;
    }

    const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
      a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
    const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
      b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

    let comparison = 0;
    if (varA > varB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (varA < varB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return (
      (order === 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
    );
  };
}

console.log(Kids.sort(compareValues('random', )));

let teamOne = [];
let teamTwo = [];

let kidName1 = {};
let kidName2 = {};

kidName1 = Kids.pop();
teamOne[0] = kidName1.name;
kidName2 = Kids.pop();
teamTwo[0] = kidName2.name;
teamOne.name = "Team 1";
teamTwo.name = "Team 2";

console.log(teamOne);
console.log(teamTwo);
console.log(Kids);

let coinToss = "Heads"

if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1) == 2) {
  coinToss = "Tails";
};

console.log(coinToss);

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    kidName1 = Kids.pop();
    kidName2 = Kids.pop();
    if (coinToss == "Heads") {
        teamOne.push(kidName1.name);
        teamTwo.push(kidName2.name);
    } else {
        teamOne.push(kidName2.name);
        teamTwo.push(kidName1.name);
    }
};
console.log("_____________");
console.log(coinToss);
console.log("_____________");
console.log(teamOne.name);
console.log("_____________");
console.log(teamTwo.name);
console.log("_____________");
console.log(teamOne.toString());
console.log("_____________");
console.log(teamTwo.toString());
```